# Path Distance Algorithm does not check each node

Tags: java, algorithm, path, while-loop

I am building a answer to a problem on codility. I don't really care about getting credit for it. It just bugs me that my solution doesn't work. 
The problem asks for a map of N nodes and N-1 pairwise paths connecting them all into one graph. Given any starting point what is the shortest path that travels through each node at least once. Similar to TSP but the are N-1 paths not N paths

The data input is a integer representing the starting node and an array representing the pairwise paths.

My solution: 
Find each node that is an edge (has only one neighbor). create an array of these nodes. create a jagged array containing the neighbors of each node (connected directly only). Find which edge is closest that hasn't been visited. go to that node. repeat the process but with a new visited array.

The return statement should return the nodes stopped at after each step as an array including the starting and end node.

I can create the edge array and the neighbor array just fine. My problem is the actual hard part. making the algorithm to find the nearest edge.

I think I have an answer but it uses a while loop and is not correctly evaluating as I would expect it to. Can you see my error?
h is the visited (h for hit) array. e is the edge array. n, the neighbor array. s, starting point. Both n and h are static.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getDistance(ArrayList<Integer> e, int s) {
    ArrayList<Integer> retArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
    int search = s;
    h.add(search);
    int dist = 0;
    while (!e.contains(search)) {
        int i=0;
        while (h.contains(n.get(search).get(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        h.add(n.get(search).get(i));
        search = n.get(search).get(i);
        dist++;
    }
    retArr.add(dist);
    retArr.add(search);
    return retArr;
}
```

Let's say the neighbor map is as follows:

[0] : [1 , 2]

[1] : [0]

[2] : [0 , 3 , 6]

[3] : [2 , 4]

[4] : [3 , 5]

[5] : [4 , 8]

[6] : [2]

[7] : [8]

[8] : [5, 7]

This would mean e is [1, 6, 7]

If you were to start at 0 the first step is 1. which is an edge node. this should end the while loop and return [1, 1]. It does go to 1 but then continues along the path 0->1->0->2->3->4->5->8->7. It then recognizes 7 as an end node and returns. This happens for every non linear graph. If the algorithm passes a edge it continues until the second edge is found.

Comment: I think you must be talking about a graph, not a tree. It is impossible to find a route through a tree that visits every node only once (a Hamiltonian path). The problem of visiting every node in a graph only once to minimize the total travel is the Traveling Salesman Problem.

Comment: Can't tell if you problem is in fact a TSP or a Minimum Spanning Tree. Would you mind posting the original question statement?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the original problem. If it helps this is looking for a Hamiltonian path in a graph of n nodes that are connected through n-1 paths.

Comment: Hamiltonian Path [is NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). TSP doesn't have n*(n-1)/2 paths (edges) but only n. TSP is the same of finding an Hamiltonian Cycle.

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusion. But I am looking for a Hamiltonian path, not a cycle.

Comment: Are the given n-1 paths pairwise edge disjoint? I.e. do they define a subdivision of some star?

Comment: @G.Bach I'm not quite understanding disjoint. The graph is connected completely in the minimum number of pairwise edges. (N-1) One example would be a straight line with two end nodes

Comment: What I mean is, do the n-1 paths overlap?

Comment: IF you were to consider the paths from edge vertice to edge vertice (0<->6, 0<->7, and 6<->7 in the example.) they do overlap. But the paths to each node do not.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that answer; do the paths you are given as input have edges in common? I assume they can, because otherwise every input graph has to be a tree, or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: @LukeSmith Hamiltonian Path is **also** NP-complete.